# JQuery Autocomplete using a global JSON object

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, autocomplete

I have a JSON array of objects that looks something like:

```
jsonObject=      
[{"description":"mac and cheese", "servingSize":"1 cup", "calories":"500"},
 {"description":"slice of pizza", "servingSize":"1 slice", "calories":"400"},
 {"description":"oreo cookie", "servingSize":"1 cookie", "calories":"100"},
 {"description":"salad", "servingSize":"1 cup", "calories":"50"},
 {"description":"apple", "servingSize":"1 apple", "calories":"70"}]
```

I am trying to create an autocomplete text box using the description field of the jsonObject.
I have tried the following code (on a textbox called "food") which does not display anything:

```
$('#food').autocomplete({source:jsonObject,
                        select: function(event, ui) {
                                       selectedObj = ui.item;
                                       alert("selected object="+selectedObj.value);},
                        minLength:1
                    });
```

I also tried creating a separate array of label/value pairs with just the descriptions from the jsonObject, but still nothing is displaying.  Can anyone see what I am missing?

I was hoping to keep the jsonObject in tact, as I am ultimately trying to access the serving size and calories associated with the chosen food "description".

EDIT:
Here is the complete code.  Perhaps this would help find the problem...

```
var jsonVersion;

$(document).ready(function($){
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "test.js",
    dataType: "text",
    success: function(data) {
                                data = $.csv.toArrays(data);
                                var arrayOfObjects = new Array();

                                for(var i=1; i<data.length; i++)//skipping over header
                                {
                                    var foodObject = new Object();
                                    foodObject.number = data[i][0];
                                    foodObject.description = data[i][1];
                                    foodObject.weight = data[i][2];
                                    foodObject.servingSize = data[i][3];
                                    foodObject.calories = data[i][4];
                                    arrayOfObjects.push(foodObject);
                                }
                                jsonVersion = JSON.stringify(arrayOfObjects);   

                            }
 });

});

$('#food').autocomplete({source:jsonVersion,
                          minLength:1
                          });
```

Comment: Do you get any errors in the browser's console? (As an aside, [there's no such thing as a JSON object](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/). What you have there is an array of objects, there's no JSON.)

Comment: Works for me  here http://jsfiddle.net/dS5YL/

Comment: I edited to add the commas.  I do have the commas in there.  I apologize for leaving those out.  Wow, it does work in your jsfiddle, PSL.  I am not getting any browser errors.

Comment: I am populating my jsonObject variable using        $(document).ready(function($){...}.  Perhaps the autocomplete is trying to access the variable before it is populated?

Comment: Edited to show complete code.  Does this help anyone spot the problem?